# VS2017 Build Explorer shows only last 7 builds -- how to extend?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to look at history in Build Explorer, and I can see only 7 builds. My local contacts tell me that's all they've ever been able to see, and they don't know how to change it. Is there a way to increase that? I Googled and nothing leapt out at me (don't really know how to frame the question for Google). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that our DevOps team has set TFS to delete all but the seven most recent builds. No local setting was / is responsible for the lack of information.